# How to execute MySQL query daily

Tags: android, mysql

I am developing an android application date takes a date from the user. Then the date is saved in a mySQL database. now I need to execute a query everyday, if the date is matched with the current date then I will send an SMS to the user. How can I run that query everyday automatically in mySQL?

Comment: mysql or sqlite? use a background process to make that query

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use cron job. Write a script that will run daily and check on the database if the date matches, it will send the SMS.

Here's the workflow of the script:

```
// rundaily.php
<?php
// run sql query to see if the date matches
    // if matches, send the sms
```

And using cron job you will have to execute the rundaily.php file everyday.

You can define a cron job on a linux environment by running the command `crontab -e`.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a MYSQL scheduler, So that you can run queries in daily base without using any cods.